# Storing the output of foreach loop into a variable

Tags: php, foreach

I have a foreach loop that will echo out all the selection made by the user from the checkboxes.

I am trying to store the value into a variable called `$getCentralArea`. However, when I echo `$getCentralArea` it shows `4` - only the last value of the selected checked box. The correct value that I should get is `1,2,3,4`.

```
if(!empty($_POST['centralArea'])) 
{
    foreach($_POST['centralArea'] as $centralArea) 
    {
        $getCentralValue = $centralArea.","; //Output will be in the following format 1,2,3,4
    }
}else{ $getCentralArea="";}
```

Comment: use this $getCentralValue .= $centralArea.","; for string or create array.

Comment: use $getCentralValue[] to make the array of all elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concatenate but that leaves a trailing comma.  Also, no need to loop, just `implode()` the array:

```
$getCentralValue = implode(',', $_POST['centralArea']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate your `$centralArea`s to `$getCentralValue` using the `.` (or `.=`) operator, else, it just overwrites `$getCentralValue` every time you loop:

```
if(!empty($_POST['centralArea'])) 
{
    foreach($_POST['centralArea'] as $centralArea) 
    {
        $getCentralValue .= $centralArea.","; //Output will be in the following format 1,2,3,4
    }
    $getCentralValue = rtrim($getCentralValue, ",");
} else{ $getCentralArea=""; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this: **Use implode.**

either

```
$result=implode(",",$_POST['centralArea']);//Output will be in the following format 1,2,3,4
```

or this in case you do not want post variables to use directly.

```
      $getCentralValue=array();
        foreach($_POST['centralArea'] as $centralArea) 
        {
            $getCentralValue[]= $centralArea; 
        }

        $result=implode(",",$getCentralValue);//Output will be in the following format 1,2,3,4

    echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather push them in array and later print them using implode

```
if(!empty($_POST['centralArea'])) 
            {
              $stack = array();
                foreach($_POST['centralArea'] as $centralArea) 
                {
                    array_push($stack,$centralArea);
               }
//print in 1,2,3,4
$comma_separated = implode(",", $stack);

echo $comma_separated;

            }
```